# Use of composite keys

Tags: mysql, database, composite-key

I'm new to the concept of composite key's, I have not understood the use of composite key's in a real world scenario. In all the real world scenario's I have thought of I can do the same with out a composite key.

Comment: Basically, any time you have a many-to-many relationship, the link table will have a composite key comprising foreign key columns to both sides of that relationship. Most often, this composite can be your PRIMARY KEY, but (very) occasionally it can make more sense to call this a UNIQUE KEY, and have a 'surrogate'  PRIMARY KEY column (commonly called `id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one scenario where you will find it usefull  say suppose you are working as an editor and have a database with books.Now you need a table that stores editorial comments about each page in each book.

The unique identifier will be book_id and pageNumber (normalized since we have book information in a separate table).

Now since we pretty much can guarantee that each book will contain overlapping page numbers we can't put a primary key on pageNumber and we certainly can't put a primary key on book_id.
And in this case we want to guarantee that we only have on row per page per book.

Instead the natural identifier is (book_id, pageNumber) so that is what we choose. Because that will be the unique identifier for each page.

You may read this [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17748286-7539-48d0-b0d1-14791126ab46/what-is-use-composite-key-?forum=databasedesign) link:

> Composite keys are used when there is no a single field uniquelly
>   identifying each row i a table. Then you need to take more fields
>   together to get a primary key of a table, which is then called
>   composite key.
>
> **For example**, you have a customers table with the following fields:
>   First name, Last name, Date of birth, Address, Gender. To uniquelly
>   identify a customer, you have to know his First name, Last name, Date
>   of birth and Address - this would be a composit key (two customers
>   with the same name and address can exist as well as two with the same
>   name and birthday).

Comment: Thank you this is the best explanation of composite key that I have read so far.